# How to filter more than one property in Google AppEngine? (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a problem using queries that are using more than one filter (I am using NDB instead DB):

```
...
foo = something.query(something.a==5, something.b<8, something.c<3).order(something.b).fetch(1)
...
```

I am getting this error:

```
Only one inequality filter per query is supported.
```

I could solve this problem by using something like this:

```
...
foo = something.query(something.a==5, something.b<8).order(something.b).fetch()
#loop through each one of those rows and add those who have foo.c<3 to some array
```

but that solution is not really great. Does anybody have some better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
foo = something.query(ndb.query.AND(something.a==5, something.b<8, ndb.query.OR(something.c==1, something.c==2)))
```

Comment: Clever. You can simplify this to: something.query(something.a==5, something.b<8, something.c.IN([1, 2])): you get the topmost AND level for free, and IN is an implied OR on the same property and different values. But in general the restriction itself remains -- you cannot use <, <=, >, >= or != on more than one property in the same query. (!= translates into < OR >.)

Comment: This doesn't solve the general problem though - what if you wanted something.c < 100?

Comment: @GuidovanRossum What if something.c is a float ? Like in this case [multiple inequality comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980755/ndb-multi-inequality-comparision-join-multi-queries-cursors-python-googl). Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a related problem, and I used a ComputedProperty to solve it.  Eg, you could have a ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.b < 8 and self.c < 3) and then just query for whether that ComputedProperty is true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [query.AND or query.OR](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or):

```
qry = Article.query(query.AND(Article.tags == 'python',
                              query.OR(Article.tags.IN(['ruby', 'jruby']),
                                       query.AND(Article.tags == 'php',
                                                 Article.tags != 'perl'))))
```

Comment: I got same error. I am using more than one property. In your example you're using tags only, but I need to use a,b,c.

Comment: @Vizualni you can add whatever you like instead any of the `.tags` in the current example...

Comment: @Lipis I know that sir :). I changed this to work with my app, but I got same error. This is the problem that's bothering me.
[Restriction on queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries)

Comment: @Vizualni well it's a restriction that you can overpass... I guess you have to filter out the second query manually if there is no other way to model it..